# Learn Python the hard way excercise 47 nosetests NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn Python 3 from the book Learn Python 3 the hard way but I run into an error trying to run the test using nosetests in excercise 47 Running my commands inside the top ex47 directory.

My folder structure is:

```
ex47
  -bin
  -docs
  -ex47
      __init__.py
      game.py
  -test
      __init__.py
      ex47_tests.py
  setup.py
```

The content of **init** files is blank. For the other files it is:
game.py

```
class Room(object):

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.paths = {}

    def go(self, direction):
        return self.paths.get(direction, None)

    def add_paths(self, paths):
        self.paths.update(paths)
```

setup.py

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutials.core import setup

config = {
    'decription' : 'My Project',
    'author' : 'My Name',
    'url' : 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url' : 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email' : 'My Email',
    'version' : '0.1',
    'install_requires' : ['nose'],
    'packages' : ['ex47'],
    'scripts' : [],
    'name' : 'ex47'
}

setup(**config)
```

ex47_tests.py

```
from nose.tools import *
import ex47

def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, {})

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({'north' : north, 'south' : south})
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You van go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

    start.add_paths({'west' : west, 'down' : down})
    west.add_paths({'east' : start})
    down.add_paths({'up' : start})

    assert_equal(start.go('west'), west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

Trying to run this in PowerShell gives me these errors relating to the class Room not beïng found.
[image]

Comment: either `from ex47 import *` or use `ex47.Room`

Comment: Try to avoid using `from module import *` as it abstracts any method used from the module and makes your code harder to read!

Comment: yes you need to import, your stack trace is clear, Room is not in your namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should access top-level modules here. for example add this line in your   `__init__.py` :

```
__all__ = ["game"]
```

Then, import that like another ones

```
from game import Room
```

Also you can use top level directory :

```
from ex34.game import Room
```

Or in a simple way, put all files in one directory to access them easily

```
ex47
  game.py
  ex47_tests.py
  setup.py
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Because the book tells you to copy/paste a skeleton structure I missed changing the import in ex47_test.py. This indeed needs to be from ex47.game import Room. Stupid mistake... wasted time....

Comment: Forget this books or exercise projects. Try to look at official documents and write program yourself. Also you can watch good learning videos from professional companies like `Lynda` @PietHein